# Testing methods using SqlConnection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit, .net-7.0

How can I write unit tests in XUnit to a method, in which I use SqlConnection? I have several such methods (eg. validation of provided connection string, creating, dropping and executing sql procedures). In this part of application I don't want to use EF (I really can't do this in this part of my app). So my question is based on one example but it applies to many more methods.

The following method checks if a chosen database (provided in connection string) is compatible with chosen software version. If versions are compatible, procedure returns 1.
This is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckSoftwareVersion(SoftVersion softVersion, string connectionString)
        {
            _sqlProceduresService.CreateProcedure(connectionString, "someProcedure.sql");


            using (SqlConnection connection = new(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                var tran = connection.BeginTransaction();
                command.Transaction = tran;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "someProcedure";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SoftVersion", (int)softVersion);
                try
                {
                    var scalarResult = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (scalarResult is null)
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("...");
                        return false;
                    }
                    tran.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("...");
                    tran.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            };

            _sqlProceduresService.DropProcedure(connectionString, "[dbo].[someProcedure]");

            await Task.CompletedTask;
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: If you involve another component in your Unit Tests than its not a Unit Test anymore. In Unit Test other parts of the Application that require connection to them are Mocked. The main purpose of Unit Tests is to test your code.

Comment: Of course. So in this example I can mock _sqlProceduresService, that's not a problem. But I have no idea how to test the rest of my code.

Comment: You're trying to test SqlConnection and SqlCommand? Since besides that I don't see any major logic that needs to be tested in the method you have provided. If you're trying to unit test a stored procedure than this might be helpful - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-create-unit-tests-for-functions-triggers-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver16